# How to prove that $\mathbb E(x^n)-\mathbb E(x)^n \ge 0; \quad n \in \mathbb Z_+.$

Tags: probability, means, moment-generating-functions

How to prove that $$\mathbb E(X^n)-\mathbb E(X)^n \ge 0; \quad n \in \mathbb Z_+.$$

X is a R.V. in the range of $[0, 1]$

Any hints appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [Jensen inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $f(x)=x^n,x\in[0,1]$ is convex function,so by the Jensen's inequality:
\begin{equation}
  E(f(X))=E(X^n)\geq f(E(X))=E(X)^n
\end{equation}